# Can I make Windows 7 process the IPsec INITIAL-CONTACT message?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ipsec

Windows 7 seems to ignore the IPsec INITIAL-CONTACT notification described in RFC 2407. Is there a setting to make it process the message? When Windows receives the notification, it should delete its security associations with the sender and renegotiate Phase 2.